# Regression Model | glm function

Tags: linear-regression, glm

I'm trying to get the logistic model, but so far I can only calculate the estimate for the intercept and SBP_category when I intend to look at all individually.

The middle part I don't know if it makes sense to use it.

So far, I got this:

```
data_CHD <- data.frame(
  SBP_category = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),  labels = c("<117", "117 - 126", "127 - 136", "137 - 146", "147 - 156", "157 - 166", "167 - 176", ">177")
  CHD = c(3, 17, 12, 16, 12, 8, 16, 8),
  No_CHD = c(153, 235, 272, 255, 127, 77, 83, 35)
)


data_CHD$SBP_category <- factor(data_CHD_, levels = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),  labels = c("<117", "117 - 126", "127 - 136", "137 - 146", "147 - 156", "157 - 166", "167 - 176", ">177") 
                  

res_binom <- glm(cbind(CHD, No_CHD) ~ SBP_category, family = "binomial", data = data_CHD)
summary(res_binom)
```

---

```
> summary(res_binom)                    

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(CHD, No_CHD) ~ SBP_category, family = "binomial", 
    data = data_CHD)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.9504  -0.6680  -0.2847   0.2591   1.9474  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -3.42264    0.22065 -15.512  < 2e-16 ***
SBP_category  0.26943    0.05504   4.895 9.81e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 30.0226  on 7  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.3948  on 6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 43.096

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: The tag [gml] is used for "game-maker-language", does this apply to your question?

Comment: Sorry I switched the letters :(